# How do I copy a movie DVD to my Linux box?

Tags: dvd

How can I copy a movie from a DVD to my Linux box? I believe that the program **k9copy** used to do this, but **k9copy** is long defunct.  I'm running Kubuntu 21.10. (I realize that the answer can be very much version-dependent.

Now that **makemkv** is out of beta, it is no longer free.  **handbrake** apparently can do the job, but i couldn't see how to use it with a USB DV drive (though I can play dvd movies from that drive with VLC).

The tomtomtom repository isn't usable because it doesn't have a release file.

Comment: Please specify the Ubuntu version. In the terminal: egrep '^(VERSION)=' /etc/os-release && echo $DESKTOP_SESSION. DVD Rippers: acidrip, handbrake. For Ubuntu Bionic: dvdrip, k9copy-reloaded project https://launchpad.net/~tomtomtom/+archive/ubuntu/k9copy

Comment: MakeMKV see here: https://forum.makemkv.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=224 and here: https://forum.makemkv.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=1053

Comment: I'm running Kubuntu21.10.  Please see revised question. Now that makemkv is out of beta, it is no longer free.

Comment: The tomtomtom repository isn't usable because it doesn't have a release file.

Comment: handbrake doesn't seem to be able to work with USB DVD drives.